# SQL Schema setup

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am newer to SQL and a bit confused on how best to represent an Entity-Relationship diagram for the following:

Say we have a company. The company has employees. Employees have managers (Many employees to 1 manager). Managers are employees (but managers can't manage themselves). Each employee/manager can be on many projects (1 emp/manager to Many projects). Also, employees/managers have many roles at the company (1 emp/manager to Many roles).

I am most confused on how to take into account embedding managers within employees. Are there any constraints that I would need to include to ensure no manager manages themselves?

Here is my schema so far (PostgreSQL):

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    emp_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    manager_id INTEGER REFERENCES managers (manager_id)
);


CREATE TABLE managers
(
    manager_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE projects
(
    project_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    project_name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    emp_id       INTEGER REFERENCES employees (emp_id)
);


CREATE TABLE roles
(
    role_id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    role_name VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    emp_id    INTEGER REFERENCES employees (emp_id)
);
```

Any thoughts and help is much appreciated!

Comment: Don't ref employee from project. Instead, create a new table called "project_member" that has ref to employee and project. Similarly, create a "assignment" table that has the ref to role and employee, so you can have as many roles as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make the following amendments to your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE employees
(
    emp_id     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name       VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    -- instead of: manager_id INTEGER REFERENCES managers (manager_id)
    manager_id INTEGER REFERENCES employees (emp_id)
);

-- ...and remove:
--CREATE TABLE managers
--(
--    manager_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
--    name       VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
--);
```

If you really want to encode the "no manager manages themselves" rule as a DB constraint, you could add a `CHECK` constraint (`emp_id <> manager_id`).